# browser insecure content warning, no http:// in db or WP theme

Tags: wordpress, insecure-connection

The browser says a [client-managed site](https://vivescoal.com.au/) is insecure. If I check in Firefox > Media, I can see no files delivered over http://.

If I check https://www.whynopadlock.com/results/11d3f0c2-a944-43c0-922a-92a0cbe7b5c2 it says there are 3 image files delivered over http://

- http://www.vivescoal.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/logo.png
- http://www.vivescoal.com.au/wp-content/themes/balance/images/button_icon.png
- http://www.vivescoal.com.au/wp-content/themes/balance/images/dark_backgrounds/background9.jpg

I can't find these URLs in the database, nor in the parent theme or child theme.

Help appreciated to see where in the site these files are being called.

Comment: Have you checked the theme settings in the Wordpress backend? I don't know this particular theme, but usually stuff like this in the settings somewhere.

Comment: @Frank, I have, and those settings would also be in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I cannot add images to comment, I'm adding it here. This is what I see is happening:
[image]

The image is called from a different domain, then redirected with a 301 to the non-https version. There is either something wrong in the litespeed configuration or the webserver configuration of that domain. It should not be redirecting https to http.

Comment: Brilliant. How did you pick up those requests for the different domain please?

Comment: This is simply the browser console of Google Chrome. I used the 'network' tab and filtered on the word `logo`. This gave 3 results which gave it away :). Glad I could help.